# Layout in RelativeLayout Doesn't Respond to Inputs in iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In iOS, a tap event isn't fired when tapped on the inner layout (in this case up and long tap). Works perfectly on Android. I've tried updating Xamarin.Forms, using normal gesture recogniser, using Mr. Gestures, all got the same result. What am I doing wrong here? Could anypne please help me, I've trying for weeks now. Thank you for your time.

```
<RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="White">
  <xlabs_c:GesturesContentView x:Name="MainLayout"
       ExcludeChildren ="False"
       Padding="10"
       RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
       "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                              Property=Width,
                              Factor=1}"
       RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
       "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                              Property=Height,
                              Factor=1}">
    <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <ContentView
         RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                Property=Width,
                                Factor=1}"
         RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                Property=Height,
                                Factor=1}">
        <xlabs_b:Gestures.Interests>
          <xlabs_b:GestureCollection>
            <xlabs_b:GestureInterest GestureType="Up" GestureCommand="{Binding OnMainLayoutRetractSidebarCommand}"/>
            <!--<xlabs_b:GestureInterest GestureType="Swipe" Direction="Left" GestureCommand="{Binding OnMainLayoutSwipedCommand}"/>
            <xlabs_b:GestureInterest GestureType="Swipe" Direction="Right" GestureCommand="{Binding OnMainLayoutSwipedCommand}"/>-->
          </xlabs_b:GestureCollection>
        </xlabs_b:Gestures.Interests>
        <RelativeLayout x:Name="LayoutWrapper" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
          <Image x:Name="BackgroundImage" Aspect="AspectFill" SizeChanged="OnBackgroundImageSizeChanged"/>
          <RelativeLayout x:Name="PinsLayout"
             RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
             "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
                                    Property=Width,
                                    Factor=1,
                                    ElementName=BackgroundImage}"
             RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
             "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
                                    Property=Height,
                                    Factor=1,
                                    ElementName=BackgroundImage}"/>
          <xlabs_b:Gestures.Interests>
            <xlabs_b:GestureCollection>
              <xlabs_b:GestureInterest GestureType="LongPress" GestureCommand="{Binding OnLayoutWrapperTappedCommand}"/>
            </xlabs_b:GestureCollection>
          </xlabs_b:Gestures.Interests>
        </RelativeLayout>
      </ContentView>
      <ContentView InputTransparent="True"
          RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
          "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                Property=Width,
                                Factor=1}"
          RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
          "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                Property=Height,
                                Factor=1}">
        <StackLayout x:Name="PageNumberLayout" InputTransparent="True" Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End"/>
      </ContentView>
    </RelativeLayout>
  </xlabs_c:GesturesContentView>
  <StackLayout x:Name="SidebarLayout"
       Padding="10"
       BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
       Opacity="0"
       IsVisible="False"
       IsEnabled="False"
       Spacing="10"
       RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
       "{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,
                              Property=Width,
                              Constant=400}"
       RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
       "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                              Property=Height,
                              Factor=1}">
    <StackLayout x:Name="FloorListLayout" IsVisible="False" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Frame CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" Padding="10">
          <Label Style="{StaticResource DefaultInvertLabel}" Text="{x:Static resx:LanguageResources.SortFloorText}" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="{StaticResource LightBackgroundColor}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        </Frame>
        <ListView x:Name="FloorListView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Floor}"
            HasUnevenRows="False"
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
            ItemSelected="OnFloorListViewItemSelected"
            SeparatorVisibility="Default"
            SeparatorColor="{StaticResource Accent}"
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
            RowHeight="75">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10">
                  <Frame Padding="5" CornerRadius="10" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSourceBytes, Converter={StaticResource IBytesToImageSourceConverter}}" />
                  </Frame>
                  <Label Style="{StaticResource DefaultInvertLabel}" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>
              </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
      </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout x:Name="DefectListLayout" IsVisible="False" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <!-- Function is obsoleted until further notice -->
      <!--
        <Button x:Name="MasterDefectButton" Text="{x:Static resx:LanguageResources.MasterDefectSelectLabelText}" Clicked="OnMasterDefectButtonClicked"/>
        <Button x:Name="DefectButton" Text="{x:Static resx:LanguageResources.DefectSelectLabelText}" IsVisible="False" Clicked="OnDefectButtonClicked"/>
        <Button x:Name="SubDefectButton" Text="{x:Static resx:LanguageResources.SubDefectSelectLabelText}" IsVisible="False" Clicked="OnSubDefectButtonClicked"/>
        -->

      <Frame CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" Padding="10">
        <Label Style="{StaticResource DefaultInvertLabel}" Text="{x:Static resx:LanguageResources.SortDefectText}" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="{StaticResource LightBackgroundColor}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
      </Frame>
      <ListView x:Name="DefectsListView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Defects}"
            HasUnevenRows="False"
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
            ItemSelected="OnDefectListViewItemSelected"
            SeparatorVisibility="Default"
            SeparatorColor="{StaticResource Accent}"
            RowHeight="75">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <StackLayout Padding="10">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                  <Label Style="{StaticResource DefaultInvertLabel}" Text="{Binding ID}" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                  <Label Style="{StaticResource DefaultInvertLabel}" Text=". " FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                  <Label Style="{StaticResource DefaultInvertLabel}" Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <Label Style="{StaticResource DefaultInvertLabel}" Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="Default" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
              </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Since relative layouts have Z-ordering chances are you are covering up the view with the long press registered. In android(If I am rembering correctly) you can have a stack of gesture recognizers and each one returns whether or not it handled the touch event. The event will eventually work its way up the view stack till its handled or not; which makes it work at times when iOS doesn't. .. If you provide a screen shot and highlight where the problem is that will probably help.

Comment: I've also tried with only a RelativeLayout with just a single StackLayout inside. I got the same result.